# Get current Apache version string for display

Tags: windows, apache, apache2, version

I'm writing an Apache module and want to get a string with the Apache name version and other details. Much like what gets added to outgoing headers, e.g.:

```
Server: Apache/2.2.13 (Win32)
```

I've tried code like this:

```
apr_table_get(request_rec->headers_out,"Server")
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Is there an API call I haven't found or am I doomed to get version resource data from httpd.exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it: [ap_get_server_version](http://httpd.apache.org/dev/apidoc/apidoc_ap_get_server_version.html), my HTTPD2 API wrapper was missing this declaration

Answer (score 0):

try this command

```
apache2 -v
```

should print out something like this

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.11 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Mar  9 2010 21:05:51
```

most unix commands have a -v option

it looks like you are trying to get it from php, the exec command in php will let you run the command on the server

Comment: I'm not running this from PHP. I don't want to start extra processes, and am looking to get this from the Apache API somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Apache modules, but for CGI scripts, the name of the current web server is stored in the `SERVER_SOFTWARE` environment variable. In Perl, for example, you would use `$ENV{SERVER_SOFTWARE}` to read it. In C you would use `getenv ("SERVER_SOFTWARE")`.

In order to find out the server software, why not just grep through the Apache source codes to find where this is defined.

Doing this with Apache 1.3.41, I find that it is defined in a file called `util_script.c` on line 240 as follows:

```
ap_table_addn(e, "SERVER_SOFTWARE", ap_get_server_version());
```

It looks like there is a function called `ap_get_server_version` which returns the value as a string.

Comment: nope, I've checked GetEnvironmentStrings, nothing like SERVER_SOFTWARE, or anything holding version info about Apache. Note that I am developing an Apache module, which is quite different than CGI.